# How to merge items in a list of lists

Tags: python

How can I merge lists that have identical values at `index[0]`

```
[['Vienna', 3, 42, 0], ['London', 4, 11, 1], ['Vienna', 1, 8, 2]]
```

My question still stands but I will rephrase it.  How can I merge multiple list items with the same element at `index[0]` and add the integers from their respective index locations.

For example, my desired end result would be:

```
[['Vienna', 4, 40, 2], ['London', 4, 11, 1]]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a dictionary that has duplicate keys, only one will persist the other will be overwritten/discarded. How is this dictionary being populated/created? That will be your chance to merge as it's being filled.

Comment: It's a list, not a dictionary. I tried making it into a dictionary and realized that I inadvertently wrote over some of the data.  The list is a list of lists that looks like: [['Vienna', 2, 38, 0], ['London', 4, 11, 1]]

Comment: Will the number of items in the lists always be 4?

Comment: @CoryKramer Hey, thanks for your response.  I populated the dictionary by writing a for loop to update an empty dictionary.  I did not realize that every time I updated the dictionary with a repeated key, it would overwrite the previous key/value pair.  The original data structure is a list of lists.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Yes, the number of items in each list will always be 4. One string followed by 3 integers

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting from a list of lists, you can perform the merge as you are reading sublists in. If the key is present in your dictionary, perform a merge by summing element-wise in a list comprehension against the existing list. If no key is present, just store the new list directly.

```
data = [['Vienna', 3, 42, 0], ['London', 4, 11, 1], ['Vienna', 1, 8, 2]]
myDict = {}
for sub in data:
    key = sub[0]
    values = sub[1:]
    if key in myDict:
        myDict[key] = [i+j for i,j in zip(values, myDict[key])]
    else:
        myDict[key] = values
```

Result

```
>>> myDict
{'Vienna': [4, 50, 2], 'London': [4, 11, 1]}
```

If you would like to end with a list of lists, you can process the `.items()` from the resulting dict

```
>>> [[k] + v for k,v in myDict.items()]
[['Vienna', 4, 50, 2], ['London', 4, 11, 1]]
```

Comment: expected output is list of list tho

Comment: @Dragonborn The OP went back and forth on that, but if they indeed want to end up with a list of lists that is trivial using the final dict `[[k] + v for k,v in myDict.items()]`, see the above edit

Answer (score 1):

This one also takes care of variable list length if it is possible!

```
a = [['Vienna', 3, 42, 0], ['London', 4, 11, 1], ['Vienna', 1, 8, 2]]
r = {}
final = []
for x in a:
    if x[0] not in r:
        r[x[0]] = x[1:]
    else:
        key = x[0]
        other = r[key]
        current = x[1:]
        output = []
        max_idx = max(len(other), len(current))
        for i in range(0,max_idx):
            left = 0
            try:
                left = current[i]
            except:
                pass
            right = 0
            try:
                right = other[i]
            except:
                pass
            output.append(left+right)
        r[key] = output

for key, item in r.items():
    final.append([key] + item)

print(final)
```

Comment: i think your solution is unnecessary complicated with too nests. but good attempt

Comment: this is nice, what does `idx` stand for?

Answer (score 0):

Below is my edited Answer, Sorry I misunderstood the expected output.

```
data= [['Vienna', 3, 42, 0], ['London', 4, 11, 1], ['Vienna', 1, 8, 2]]

dup = {}
final = []

for item in data:
    if item[0] in dup.keys():
        dup[item[0]] = [i+j for i,j in zip(dup[item[0]], item[1:])]
    else:
        dup.update({item[0]:item[1:]})
        
for key, value in dup.items():
    final.append([key]+value)

print(final)
```

Output:

```
[['Vienna', 4, 50, 2], ['London', 4, 11, 1]]
```

Comment: Though I am not the downvoter, but I believe it was because you had to sum the values up too during merging. See in OP's question: `add the the integers from their respective index locations`